# Will application performance decrease as number of recordsets increase in SQL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, performance, recordset

I have a scenario where the sp returns around 30 recordsets. If I reduce the number of recordsets, then I have to write many loops in C# to retrieve the data and put it into the correct buckets. Is it beneficial to reduce the number of recordsets in SQL and increase the looping and code complexity in C#?

Comment: maybe, maybe not. You'll have to try it and see

Answer (score 1):

That depends on many factors like

- The network bandwith and latency between the webserver and the sqlserver
- The kind and amount of data you query

Normally its better in terms of performance to reduce the number of roundtrips to the database. But if the amount of data you have to retrieve is really big, the responiveness of your application might decrease.

Its hard to tell without knowing more about the specific needs of your app.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to process the exact same number of records and have exactly the same number of loops in your database access code whether you return 30 recordsets or have 30 stored procedures that return the same data.

There will be a slight performance benefit to the 30 recordset approach since you don't have to build commands for and execute 30 different stored procedures to retrieve the data.

However, I believe that the overall impact to the database and application, especially in terms of memory consumption, will be greater with the 30 recordset approach. With this approach, something (either SQL Server or your application) has to keep the retrieved data somewhere while your application code processes it. If you use the sp approach, then the data that is held for processing at any given point in the processing will usually be substantially smaller with the sp approach.

There is also a potential issue with database concurrency and locking with respect to the performance. If you retrieve all data in a single sp, the overall data retrieval rate could be lower due to having to wait for locks to clear before continuing with the next set of data in the stored proc. This means higher memory consumption for a longer period of time. With the sp approach, the retrieval may block for the same amount of time, but the memory consumption will be lower on average since something is not having to hold the already retrieved data until the lock has cleared.

However, unless you are executing tens of thousands of transactions per hour or your recordsets contain gigabytes of data, I don't think that changing the approach will have a significant impact on your application, so you will need to choose what you think is best from a maintainability standpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure in what case returning 30 record sets from one stored procedure is more desirable than returning less record sets but calling more than one stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on you application, do you need all the data from each data set.

Add extra roundtrips to your database normally decreases performance. But you never know till you try (or do a full code review).